# how to convert firestore TIMESTAMPS to full dates with vue Js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I want to convert the timestamp I get from the Google firestore to days and months in my vueApp.

I get an object like this `Object { seconds: 1549843200, nanoseconds: 0 }`

```
<template>
   <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" class="note">
     <div class="note_dates">
       <span class="day">{{note.day}}</span>
       <span class="month">{{note.month}}</span>
       .........
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      notes: []
    };
  },

  methods: {},
  created() {
    notesCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const query = {
          id: doc.id,
          content: doc.data().content,
          day: doc.data().created_on,
          month: doc.data().created_on
        };

        this.notes.push(query);
      });
    });
  }
```

the value `created_on` is a timestamp in the firestore collection

So, in my view component, I want to echo just the day and the month from the timestamp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take the `seconds` value from the timestamp, multiply by 1000 to get the ms value, and use `Date()`:

```js
  let timestamp = { seconds: 1549843200, nanoseconds: 0 } // firebase data     
  let myDate = new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000) // date object
  
  console.log(myDate)
```

From there,  you can extract the month/day/year or otherwise format the date [exactly as you would any other javascript Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Comment: there are multiple documents with different timestamps

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll need any external libraries for your use case. Firestore timestamps have a method that returns a date object, so what you could do is:

1. convert timestamp to date object:

   ```
    const query = {
     id: doc.id,
     content: doc.data().content,
     date: doc.data().created_on.toDate()
   };
   ```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate

2. Use built-in Date methods to get the numerical day and month:

`{{ date.getDate() }}`  and
`{{ date.getMonth() + 1 }}`

*Months start counting from 0, so december is 11*

If you want to format the date differently, I'd first try if you can use Intl.DateTimeFormat. If that doesn't offer what you need I'd pick something from date-fns that meets your needs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Daniel's answer above...there are several date libraries out there...I find [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) very useful.

Example:

```
import moment from "moment"

let myDate = created_on.seconds * 1000 // Unix ms timestamp

let myDay = moment(myDate, 'x').format('dddd') // Monday
let myMonth = moment(myDate, 'x').format('MMM') // January
```

[Full Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) here